# How should I greet two people sharing the same first name in an email?

Tags: names, greetings

I'm sending an email to two persons with the same first name (Steve)

Greeting them by saying "Hi Steve, Steve" seems totally awkward.
Is there a good way of writing this, besides leaving out their first names completely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think "Hi Steve and Steve" or even "Hi Steves" work fine.

Comment: I was going to say that, and then saw that the OP wanted to avoid mentioning any first name. I'm not sure why.

Comment: quite the contrary, sorry if my question is unclear. I want to mention first names, and I'm wondering how to do so !

Comment: "Steve and Steve" or "Steves" would work, but it's awkward; I doubt in practice that most would use first names in this situation, instead opting for the more general "gentlemen."

Comment: _Hi Steve & Steve_ works well, I think.  I find _Hi Steves_ clumsy.

Comment: And there's a certain jokiness about 'Steve and Steve'.

Comment: @Barrie: interesting; to my ear, “Hi Steve and Steve” is a pretty much neutral equivalent of eg “Hi Steve and Janet”, while “Hi Steves” would be the somewhat flippant choice.

Comment: I'm with PLL but it's very interesting to see how differently these come across to people

Comment: I'd agree that "Hi Steve and Steve" is the most "neutral" way to go about it, while still mentioning the name.

Answer (score 9):

If you know their last names, you could do something such as "Hi Steve G. and Steve A.," (assuming hypothetical last name initials).

Comment: This is exactly what I would do -- also use their last names, last initials, or possibly some other identification, like "Steve in Atlanta and Steve in Philly". If you were discussing something that included both of them and needed to refer to just one, this is what you would do. Like, "Regarding the new accounting system, Steve G. suggested we go ahead with the present plan while Steve A. wants further review."

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the relationship you have with them. If they're close friends, you could say 'Hi, you two.'

Answer (score 1):

There are several greetings that would work much better in this situation. "Gentlemen" or "Dear Gentlemen" are your best bets, as they work well in formal and casual situations. However, the answer truly depends on how well you are acquainted with the recipients; if you know them well, using "Gentlemen" may seem a bit awkward. "Hey guys" bears a more casual, friendly tone that might be better received by closer friends.

Answer (score 1):

As you are on first names terms with both of them, *Hi Steve and Steve* should be perfect and should sound fine to the mail recipients as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are these two Steves part of the same social group? Would many people know both of them? If so, my choice, in an informal context, would be *Hello the Steves*. Addressing the two of them together as *The Steves* would make less sense if they are not part of the same social grouping. Also, I wouldn't recommend it in a formal context.